# No me sale hacer responsive el header. Adjunto el codigo HTML y CSS

Tags: html, css

No logro poder hacer responsive el header, cuando salgo de la pantalla completa y la empiezo a achicar todo se desordena y los elementos se empiezan a poner unos encimas de otros. Quisiera que cuando la ventana este de menor tamaño el diseño no se pierda y se adapte al tamaño de la ventana. Alguien tiene una solucion? He tratado pero no me sale.  Apreciaria bastante el apoyo con esto. Es lo ultimo que me falta pero como mencione el header no lo logro hacer responsive. Ese es todo el problema del codigo.

```css
.header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    top: 0;
}

nav {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(250, 252, 250), #5b5f5a);
    border-radius: 25px;
    width: 98%;
    height: 85px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 1%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    z-index: 1;
}

.logo {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -65%;
    left: 10%;

}


nav ul li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 40px;
}

nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(168, 45, 45);
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;

}

li a:hover {

    color: rgb(250, 244, 238);
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
}

.video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}

@media (min-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
    .video {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
}

@media (max-aspect-ratio: 16/9) {
    .video {
        width: auto;
        height: 100%;
    }
}


i {
    margin-left: 7px;
    padding-top: 6px;
}

.iconosocial {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
    top: 28%;
    left: 82%;
    text-align: center;
}

.iconosocial ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 6%;
    left: 91%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    display: flex;
}

.iconosocial ul li {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 20px;
}

.iconosocial ul li .fab {

    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 60px;
    transition: .3s;
    color: black;
}

.iconosocial ul li a:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.iconosocial ul li a {

    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 41px;
    height: 48px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding-right: 8px;
    background-color: rgb(245, 243, 243);
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0.1);
    transition: .6s;
}

.iconosocial a {
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    font-size: 35px;
}

.iconosocial :nth-child(1) a:hover {
    background-color: rgb(12, 35, 243);
}

.iconosocial :nth-child(2) a:hover {
    background-color: rgb(243, 12, 185);

}

.iconosocial :nth-child(3) a:hover {
    background-color: rgb(18, 175, 238);

}

.texto-debajo {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 3%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.texto-debajo {
    background-image: linear-gradient(orange, rgb(128, 89, 18));
    border-radius: 30px;
    margin-left: 1%;
}

.texto-debajo p {
    font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
    <video autoplay loop muted plays-inline class="video">
        <source src="images1/videoojeda.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <div class="contenedor">
        <nav>
            <img src="images1/logo.png" class="logo">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Inicio</a></li>
                <li><a href="nosotros.html">Quienes somos</a></li>
                <li><a href="portafolio.html">Portafolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="servicios.html">Servicios</a></li>
                <li><a href="testimonios.html">Testimonios</a></li>
                <li><a href="contacto.html">Contacto</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="iconosocial">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="https://facebook.com" target="_blank">
                            <i class="fa-brands fa-facebook"></i>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="https://instagram.com" target="_blank">
                            <i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="https://twitter.com" target="_blank">
                            <i class="fa-brands fa-twitter"></i>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <h1>
        <span style="--i:1;">O</span>
        <span style="--i:2;">J</span>
        <span style="--i:3;">E</span>
        <span style="--i:4;">D</span>
        <span style="--i:5;">A</span>
        <span style="--i:6;margin-left: 5vw;">M</span>
        <span style="--i:7;">A</span>
        <span style="--i:8;">R</span>
        <span style="--i:9;">K</span>
        <span style="--i:10;">E</span>
        <span style="--i:11;">T</span>
    </h1>
</div>
<div class="texto-debajo">
    <p>
        Un mercado que se dedica a la venta de diversos productos de consumo inmediato y de primera necesidad para
        satisfacer la necesidad de los clientes. <br>
        Los proveedores son confiables y se dedican a traer productos de marcas conocidas para garantizar la calidad de
        todos los productos y así también vender una gran cantidad de productos. El objetivo de la empresa <br>
        es brindar experiencia de compra conveniente y agradable en un ambiente acogedor. Se esfuerza por superar las
        expectativas de los clientes y establecer relaciones duraderas basadas en la confianza y la satisfacción.
    </p>
</div>
```